# List comprehenension in the case of countpositives

Tags: haskell, filter, list-comprehension

I think about the function to count all positives numbers in a list. My idee was

```
countPositives :: [Int] -> Int 
countPositives xs = length [ x | x <- xs, x > 0]
```

That code work, but I thinking it is possible to write with the filter function or with guards. Is it possilbe and if yes, how can I write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both approaches would be pretty straightforward.

1. Filter the collection and count it's length:

   ```
   countPositives' :: [Int] -> Int 
   countPositives' = length.filter (>0)
   ```
2. With guards:

   ```
   countPositives'' :: [Int] -> Int 
   countPositives'' [] = 0 
   countPositives'' (x:xs) | x > 0     = 1 + countPositives'' xs
                           | otherwise = countPositives'' xs
   ```

Comment: Terminology note: these are just plain guards, pattern guards are those involving patterns in the guards as in `f x | Just y <- g x = ...`

Answer (score 1):

As yet another alternative, use a fold:

```
ghci> lst = [1, 2, 4, 7, -2, -3, 0, 8]
ghci> foldr (\x i -> if x > 0 then i + 1 else i) 0 lst
5
```

Comment: Yeah, I heard about that function but is nice is possible